# wp-admin redirecting to wp-login.php

Tags: login

When I enter `http://example.com/wordpress/wp-admin` it is redirecting to `wp-login.php` page.

I checked the `index.php` of the wp-admin folder and checked the file, it is including `wp-config.php`, `wp-settings.php`, `wp-load.php` of the root folder and some files in `wp-include` folder but I am unable to figure out which function is redirecting the wp-login.php file while entering `http://example.com/wordpress/wp-admin`. I even checked `auth_redirect()` function.

Comment: wp-login.php is to take your username & password and with 'em you can still enter into your admin area. So what exactly the problem is?

Comment: Are you saying you cant see your admin dashboard even after you are logged in as the admin?

Comment: @MayeenulIslam...I dont have any problem. While entering the url "http://example.com/wordpress/wp-admin" it is redirecting to "http://example.com/wordpress/wp-login.php" file so I Just want to know that where the code is where it is redirecting to wp-login.php file. I have gone through the code but unable to find the code where it is redirecting to wp-login.php.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each call to an admin page loads the `\wp-admin\admin.php` file.

For example, from the `\wp-admin\index.php` file:

```
/** Load WordPress Bootstrap */
require_once( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/admin.php' );
```

In that file `auth_redirect()` is called.

From `\wp-admin\admin.php`:

```
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/admin.php');

auth_redirect();

// Schedule trash collection
if ( !wp_next_scheduled('wp_scheduled_delete') && !defined('WP_INSTALLING') )
    wp_schedule_event(time(), 'daily', 'wp_scheduled_delete');

set_screen_options();
```

`auth_redirect()` does the redirect. From the inline docs:

```
/**
 * Checks if a user is logged in, if not it redirects them to the login page.
 *
 * @since 1.5
 */
function auth_redirect() {

    [...]

    $login_url = wp_login_url($redirect, true);

    wp_redirect($login_url);
    exit();
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I tried the best possible ways.

1. Uploaded the fresh files in WP-Includes and WP-Admin, it didn't work.
2. I tried changing the name of plugin folder and created a blank plugins folder, it didn't work.
3. I tried uploading the fresh files of the theme, it didn't work.
4. I renamed the theme folder, no solution.
5. List item

**5. Finally I changed the wordpress password through phpmyadmin, using the new password worked for me.****